How to Numerically Solve the Steady State of a Lindblad Equation with Parity Symmetry?
I am trying to reproduce some figures from this paper. like below:
The effective Hamiltonian of the system is
\begin{align}
    H_{\text{eff}} = \frac{3g_x^2}{\omega} |e\rangle \langle e| + \frac{2g_x^2}{\omega} a^\dagger a |e\rangle \langle e| - \frac{2g_x g_z}{\omega} (\sigma_+ a^2 + \sigma_- a^{\dagger 2}) + \Omega (\sigma_+ + \sigma_-),
\end{align}
The time evolution of the density matrix $ \rho $ of the system is governed by the master equation:
\begin{align}
\frac{d\rho}{dt} = -i[H_{\text{eff}}, \rho] + \gamma \left(2\sigma_- \rho \sigma_+ - \sigma_+ \sigma_- \rho - \rho \sigma_+ \sigma_-\right),
\end{align}
where $\gamma$ represents the energy relaxation rate of the qubit. This form of the master equation includes both two-photon driving and dissipation processes.
I've been researching ways to find the steady state of a Lindblad equation that exhibits parity symmetry. In theory, the steady-state structure is well understood and relatively straightforward to analyze analytically. However, in numerical calculations, I encounter difficulties because the system has more than one steady state. This causes issues with directly solving the equation numerically, as it fails to converge to a unique solution.
Is there a method to leverage parity symmetry to decompose the equation, or any recommended approach to numerically solve a Lindblad equation with parity symmetry? I’m completely at a loss on how to proceed with this.
The code that I am using to solve the master equation is given below:
(*定义参数和哈密顿量*)
g = 2.\[Pi]*0.15*10^9;
gx = Sqrt[2]/2. g;
\[Nu] = 2.\[Pi]*3.*10^9;
geff = 4. gx^2/\[Nu];
n = 8;
\[CapitalOmega] = 2.\[Pi]*33.75*10^6;
ee = KroneckerProduct[#,#]&@{1,0};
aIdentity = IdentityMatrix[2, SparseArray]; 
bIdentity[n_] := IdentityMatrix[n, SparseArray]; 
adagTa[n_] := SparseArray[Table[{i + 1, i + 1} -> i, {i, n - 1}]]; 
adagTadag[n_] := SparseArray[(Flatten[#1, 1] & )[Table[{{i + 2, i} -> Sqrt[i]*Sqrt[i + 1], {i, i + 2} -> 0}, {i, n - 2}]]]; 
aTa[n_] := SparseArray[(Flatten[#1, 1] & )[Table[{{i + 2, i} -> 0, {i, i + 2} -> Sqrt[i]*Sqrt[i + 1]}, {i, n - 2}]]];  
{sx, sy, sz} = Table[SparseArray[PauliMatrix[i]], {i, 3}]; 
sp = (sx + I*sy)/2; 
sm = (sx - I*sy)/2; 
h1=KroneckerProduct[bIdentity[n],ee] +2KroneckerProduct[adagTa[n],ee];

h2=KroneckerProduct[aTa[n],sp]+KroneckerProduct[adagTadag[n],sm];
Heff= (8gx^2)/(3\[Nu]) h1 - geff h2 + \[CapitalOmega] KroneckerProduct[bIdentity[n],sx];
\[Rho]=Array[Subscript[rho, #1,#2][t]&,{2 n,2 n}];
\[CapitalGamma] = 2.\[Pi]*15*10^6;
\[CapitalGamma]\[Phi]=0.;
tfinal=20/\[CapitalGamma];
L\[Rho]=-I (Heff.\[Rho] - \[Rho].Heff) + \[CapitalGamma]/2. 
lindblad[sm,\[Rho]] + \[CapitalGamma]\[Phi]/4. lindblad[sz,\[Rho]];
initial=KroneckerProduct[#\Conjugate],#]&@Flatten[KroneckerProduct[ReplacePart[Table[0,n],1->1],{0,1}]];
sol=NSolve[Flatten@Table[L\[Rho][[i,j]]==0.0,{i,1,Length[\[Rho]]},{j,1,Length[\[Rho]]}] ~Join~{Tr[\[Rho]]==1.0},Flatten@\[Rho]][[1]];
\[Rho]t=Re[\[Rho]/.sol]//Chop;
\[Alpha]=1.5;
coherentState[alpha_]:=Normalize[E^(-Abs[alpha]^2/2.)*Table[alpha^k/Sqrt[k!],{k,0,n-1}]];
targetState = Normalize[coherentState[\[Alpha]] + coherentState[-\[Alpha]]];
\[Rho]s = KroneckerProduct[#\[Conjugate],#]&@targetState;

rdm[(\[Rho]ABC_)?MatrixQ, {dA_Integer /; dA >= 1, dB_Integer /; dB >= 1, dC_Integer /; dC >= 1}] /; Dimensions[\[Rho]ABC] == {dA*dB*dC, dA*dB*dC} :=   Flatten[TensorContract[ArrayReshape[\[Rho]ABC, {dA, dB, dC, dA, dB, dC}], {2, 5}], {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]; 
\[Rho]m=Re@rdm[\[Rho]t,{n,2,1}];(* \[Rho]A=rdm[\[Rho]AB,{dA,dB,1}]; \[Rho]B=rdm[\[Rho]AB,{1,dA,dB}];*)
F=Tr[\[Rho]s.\[Rho]m];
data=Table[{t \[CapitalGamma], Tr[\[Rho]s.\[Rho]m]},{t,0,tfinal,.002 tfinal }];
ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Black, Frame -> True, FrameStyle->Black, FrameTicksStyle->Black]

the code
sol=NSolve[Flatten@Table[L\[Rho][[i,j]]==0.0,{i,1,Length[\[Rho]]},{j,1,Length[\[Rho]]}] ~Join~{Tr[\[Rho]]==1.0},Flatten@\[Rho]][[1]]; \[Rho]t=Re[\[Rho]/.sol1]//Chop
output like this

I understand that this is due to the presence of parity symmetry, which results in the system not having a unique steady state. However, I’m not sure how to resolve this issue.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for your help.
